# Unable to remove faucet handles on widespread bathroom faucet

Tags: bathroom, faucet, removal

We have these faucets in a couple of bathrooms and a couple of the handles have started to squeak. I am not sure of the brand as they were developer installed. Might be Moen as a few of the other developer installed faucets in the house are Moen, but there is no visible branding.

I thought it would be a simple job to remove the handle and apply some lubricant, but for the life of me I can find no way to get them off. There are no visible set screws.

Based on my internet research it seems maybe the bottom half might be threaded but no amount of twisting or turning has yielded any results. Also thought maybe the bottom collar might be threaded or pop off, but again I have been unable to get it to budge.

Before I break the darn thing does anyone have any other suggestions?

[image]

Comment: You may want to take a look, and make a photo if possible, of the faucet connections under the vanity top up behind the back of the sink. This may offer some good clues.

Answer (score 1):

I highly suspect that this faucet is very similar to the Kingston Brass style KB961/2/3/4/5/7/8/9 as shown in this specification sheet.

https://s1.img-b.com/build.com/mediabase/specifications/kingston_brass/574937/kingston_brass_kb969_m.pdf

The faucets are secured via wide flange nuts from the underside of the sink/vanity. Each faucet assembly has an inlet water connection and then a separate small flexible hose connection from the faucet to the mixer connection on the bottom of the spout assembly. The following picture is from the above specification sheet.

[image]

Removal of this type of faucet necessitates the disconnection inlet supply line, the flexible connection to the spout mixer, and then the removal of the flange nut on the bottom. Once the nut is removed the whole faucet assembly lifts out of its mounting hole from the top.

Note that many of the more modern quarter turn type faucets from multiple manufacturers mount as shown here.

Comment: Once the faucet is removed from the mounting hole is it then serviceable? **I.E**. Can it be disassembled to be lubed, which is the goal of the OP? Or replace the cartridge?

Comment: Completely manufacturer dependent.

Comment: "*Completely manufacturer dependent*"  **I** understand that, i was trying to point out that while it is great explanation of the how the faucet may be mounted, i was not sure how it addressed the question of how to lubricate the squeaky handles. I thought perhaps you knew and just forgot to mention it.

Comment: If there are flex lines attaching to the handles, there _might_ be enough play in the lines to leave them connected. _Maybe_...